# LAN internet not working on UbuntuDDE

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I installed [UbuntuDDE](https://ubuntudde.com/) on my PC and plugged in the LAN cable. I've tested this cable also on a different computer and it's working perfectly. Unfortunately it won't work on my UbuntuDDE.

When I ran the command `ip a` it returns something like this (I copied this from the internet, but it's identical):

```bash
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I ran the command `ifconfig` it returns something like this (I copied this from my Macbook, but on my UbuntuDDE it will only return `lo:` that's kinda similar like this):

```bash
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: Are you sure that `ifconfig` does not show anything else? You may need to enable some drivers or something.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure. Which drivers do I need to enable? Could you give me some more information please? @linux-coding649

Comment: Do you know what the the LAN port hardware model is?

Comment: Oh I need of course to install the drivers from my motherboard I think? I have this motherboard: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z390-A-PRO/support#driver
But there's only an option to choose the operating system Windows 10 or Windows 11. Do you know how to download and install these for Linux? @linux-coding649